# How to copy a List<List<string>> to a class in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I've been using nested for loops to extract the data from `List<List<string>>`.

```
public class CustomerData()
{
   public string Id {get; set;};
   public string Name {get; set;};
}

var data = new List<CustomerData>();

List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
```

How can I transfer the contents of `List<List<string>>` to `List<CustomerData>` using linq?

```
// this doesn't compile
    List<CustomerData> list2 = result.Select(item =>
                item.Select(x => new CustomerData
                {
                    Id= x[0],
                    Name = x[1]
                })).ToList();
```

Comment: your class definition as `Id` and `Name` (also without types, so not compilable`), but your query is using `Source` and `Name`. Can you please cleanup your examples to match better what you're wanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra select you don't need. You should be looking for:

```
var rawData = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> {"Id A", "Name A"},
    new List<string> {"Id B", "Name B"},
    new List<string> {"Id C", "Name C"}
};

var results = rawData.Select(grouping => new CustomerData
{
    Id = grouping[0], 
    Name = grouping[1]
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I will add that this is heavily dependent on your `List<List<string>>` being accurate as for positioning of your data, but if that's what you've got to work with that's what you've got. Just be careful.